# The Callan-Symanzik equation on Peskin & Schroeder's QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, correlation-functions, greens-functions

On Peskin & Schroeder's QFT page 411, the Callan-Symanzik (CS) equation reads
$$
\left[M \frac{\partial}{\partial M}+\beta(\lambda) \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}+n \gamma(\lambda)\right] G^{(n)}\left(\left\{x_i\right\} ; M, \lambda\right)=0 \tag{12.41}
$$

My question is, I thought the strict expression for Eq.(12.41) should be
$$
\left(\left[M \frac{\partial}{\partial M}+\beta(\lambda) \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}+n \gamma(\lambda)\right] G^{(n)}\left(\left\{x_i\right\} ; M, \lambda\right)\right)\bigg\vert_{p^2=-M^2}=0 
$$
where the renormalization condition is applied at $p^2=-M^2$, arises from Eq.(12.30).

For example, when the book calculates the two-point Green function on Page 413-414, with
$$
G^{(2)}(p)=\frac{i}{p^2}+\frac{i}{p^2}\left(A \log \frac{\Lambda^2}{-p^2}+\text { finite }\right)+\frac{i}{p^2}\left(i p^2 \delta_Z\right) \frac{i}{p^2}+\cdots .\tag{12.49}
$$
applying the CS equation (omitting the $\beta(\lambda)$ term), we can obtain
$$
-\frac{i}{p^2} M \frac{\partial}{\partial M} \delta_Z+2 \gamma \frac{i}{p^2}=0 \tag{A}
$$
In this expression, I think the condition for $p^2=-M^2$ is implicit, i.e.
$$
-\frac{i}{-M^2} M \frac{\partial}{\partial M} \delta_Z+2 \gamma \frac{i}{-M^2}=0
$$
otherwise the coefficient for $2\gamma$ is rather complicated. Would my above thoughts correct?

Comment: A subscript of $p^2 = -M^2$ on a function with no momentum arguments looks like the product of a misunderstanding. Momentum cancels out of the equation which determines $2\gamma$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks for your comment. However, since we obtain the equation $(A)$ from $(12.49)$ using the CS equation, the coefficient of $2\gamma$ is just the $i/p^2$ inside $G^2$. I think $G^2=i/p^2$ only when $p^2=-M^2$ (Renormalization condition), other wise, the coefficient of $2\gamma$ is the complicated expression of $G^2$, instead of $i/p^2$.

Comment: When they act on $\delta_Z$ with $\partial_M$, they are choosing to act on only the lowest order term whose $M$ derivative survives. It is then consistent to also restrict the rest of the CS equation to this order. The complicated stuff times $\gamma$ will only need to be included for higher loop counter terms.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks for your comment, that's make sense. Could you please elaborate more on what's the order used here? Order of $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$? And the lowest order of $\gamma$ is $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$, so we only need to keep the first term inside the $12.49$. Would this correct? Thanks for your help!